# How to get screenset view (GSPluginView) in Gigya Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, gigya

After migration from `Gigya Objective-C SDK` to `Gigya Swift SDK` there's no more `GSPluginView` class that can be displayed in custom `UIView`.

Instead there is `Gigya.sharedInstance().showScreenSet(with:viewController:params:completion:)` method that displays screen set on top of passed `UIViewController`.

Is there any way to get screen set view and display it inside custom `UIView` with Gigya Swift SDK?

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so can you please post your answer?

Comment: @poohdedoo unfortunately not, still don't have solution for this. Currently using old objc version of Gigya SDK.